# SQL - text conversion

Tags: sql, text

I want to select some values from a table . I want a text output . Now what iam doing is iam writing a procedure to convert the selected values into text . But its really time consuming . Is there anythng , means any system functions or sp's in SQL  to implement this....?

Comment: Which SQL are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or what?

Comment: Please clarify which SQL dialect you are using. And please post a sample of the code you have already written.

Comment: You also need to clarify what you mean by "convert the selected values into text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like `CAST(MyCol as varchar(50))` ?

Comment: Or CONVERT(nvarchar(50), MyCol)

Comment: ...as in the English 'scans' not table scans!

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this `select CAST('some test string' AS ntext)`
Microsoft has a graph of valid casts in sql-server at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx